# Show disclaimer with accept button before redirecting to the payment gateway website

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a payment gateway for woo commerce which on placing the order at the checkout redirects the user to the payment gateway's website. I want to add a thingy such that when he clicks the place order button, before redirecting he sees a popup with a button to accept and decline. Thus he is only redirected when he clicks the accept button.